# Sql output content is produced twice in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails to develop a social website for posting, tagging etc. I am also using a gem **public_activity** and this is used to render the page. While loading the page, sometimes the post are shown twice when there is only some posts. But when I see the log of server I found queries are repeated twice ie, taken data from both database and cache and resulting in loading those posts twice.

Server log

```
 SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 836 LIMIT 1
 CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 836 LIMIT 1  [["id", 836]]
```

Please help to solve the issue . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You (or some gem) are probably calling the request twice. But in order to help you, we need you to post some code.

Comment: I think if there is any such issue then this issue will always occur. right?. But the issue is not that often. And can be removed by deleting the repeated posts. Then when new post is added the issue not occur

Comment: Use _active_record_query_trace_ to know what code running each query, it should led you the problem.